# Transparent option does not work in electron with nodeIntegration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

When I use nodeintegration in createWindow the transparency stop working and the background become white and it I set nodeintegration to false it does not render anything due to missing required

```
function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800, height: 650,
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 650,
        icon: './tpologo.png',
        titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
        frame: false,
        transparent: true,
        resizable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration:true
        }
    });
```

[image: nodeintegration: true]

[image: nodeintegration: false]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.
the problem was v-app that is for vuetify and its default background color is white